# Are there any Android Drawable designers?

Tags: android, graphics, drawable, vector-graphics

I would like to use more vector drawings in my Android applications.  Providing images isn't as space efficient or as scalable as I would like it to be.

Android provides a series of [Drawable file formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html), such as `ShapeDrawable`, which can be combined in a `LayeredDrawable`. To go very far down this path, it would be nice if there was a designer for visualizing the results, doing the drawing in, and handling all the resulting files.

C# WPF has [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx), Adobe has Flash CS4, and the iPhone has [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/).  So my question is, is there a designer or drawing tool for Android?

Note: Other questions have talked about using SVG in Android.  Android doesn't have native support for SVG, so the only way to do it is with an external library.  I would like to avoid that and am asking for a developer side tool.  An SVG to `Drawable` converter would be fine, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: I think having a visual editor for Drawables would be great as I haven't seen anything that adequately fills this need. If you decide to try and create one like you suggested on your other question let me know I might be able to help out with coding/testing. I personally use a lot of ShapeDrawables so it would be useful to me.

Comment: Whoa, still unanswered. Hasn't anybody thought of a tool like this?

Comment: [This utility](http://shapes.softartstudio.com/) is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I've just released a little library on github that allow to export svg to drawable more quickly.

https://github.com/r3gis3r/svg2drawable

Hope can be useful for you.

Comment: Looking at the source code, is it only outputting .png files?

Comment: Yes, for now only output .png file, but it would be very easy to change it in code. In the git hub repository, edit utils.py (https://github.com/r3gis3r/svg2drawable/blob/master/util.py#L74). Ligne 74.

Change .png in anything else you want (supported by PIL)

Answer (score 1):

For the sub-subset of rectangular ShapeDrawables there is a nice tool online at Angry Tools which allows one to edit a button's drawable:

http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using Vector Drawables, which are natively supported by Android 5.0+. There is an [SVG to VectorDrawable Converter](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter), so you can create SVG images in your favorite editor.

[BetterVectorDrawable](https://github.com/a-student/BetterVectorDrawable) is the VectorDrawable implementation for Android 4.0+ with configurable fall-back behavior on Android 5.0+.

**SVG to VectorDrawable Converter** is the batch converter of SVG images to Android VectorDrawable XML resource files. [Online version](http://svg2vector.com) exists.

Links point to readmes, which provide enough information on how to use the lib and the converter.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tiraisoft.drawabledesigner

It runs on Android so you can see the changes live.

Disclaimer:
I'm the author