# What is the most popular host OS for developing for Android?

Tags: java, android, wpf, gtk#

I'm thinking about writing a development tool that will support development for Android.

I realize that people running Windows, Mac OS, and Linux all develop for Android, but what are the statistics?

Personally I run Windows, and I'd prefer to write it in C# with WPF, but WPF isn't exactly cross platform.  I'm really only doing Java to target Android.

If it's cross platform, does Java make the most sense, or can it be .NET+GTK# or something like that?

EDIT: I have no intention of replacing the code editor/compiler/etc.  It was more along the line of a graphics editor.  Something that I don't think is supplied by any current tools.

Comment: This question is a perfect candidate for http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @willytate I don't agree. It is programming related thus it is spot on here.

Comment: @willytate I'd say android.stackexchange.com is more like a Super User for Android, than it is a StackOverflow for Android, so this question is fine here.

Comment: What do you mean by graphics editor?

Comment: I hadn't gotten a response to my question about a [Drawables editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859707/are-there-any-android-drawable-designers) and was thinking of writing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) is Java based. Regardless of Operating System, many developers use the [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) provided by Google, specifically the [Android Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing) for the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't thinking of replacing any tools that exist.  Some of the tools seem to be binary executables, but others are common using Java?

Comment: @Nathan, didn't assume you were, I was just suggesting that a typical setup for android development is: [SOME OS] + Java + Eclipse + Android SDK Tools + Android Eclipse Plugin, and so if you want to reach as many people as possible you should try to align your efforts with those technologies. An eclipse plugin or cross platform standalone Java program would be a good choice. Other approaches have been popular though, such as DroidDraw, which is offered as a webapp and standalone java.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to DroidDraw.  I'll look some more, but what I was thinking might just be a modification of that.  They are also showing a good example of a cross platform application.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to get involved in either the IntelliJ Android tools or Eclipse Android tools development as those are already cross-platform and most-widely used.

Reinventing the wheel is not the best idea but improving an existent one is.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of replacing any tools that exist.  I edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion, best to stick with what everyone else uses. That's Eclipse + the ADT (android dev tools) plugins. As a developer, you want to spend your time writing your apps not struggling with tools.

As for the OS, I've used Windows, Mac, and Linux and with a few very minor exceptions they work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with willytate, with this being great for android exchange.

> If it's cross platform, does Java make the most sense, or can it be .NET+GTK# or something like that?

Java does make the most sense.